# Best practice for exposing data using Web API along with building MVC4 website

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am having one client who wanted to have a website along with an app on iPhone and Android too. So, I am worried about how to structure my MVC solution architecture to best suit the requirement and re-use the business logic among all the platform using Web API.

Can any one suggest the architecture in bit detail to prefer in the above mentioned requirement.

Comment: What is pp?  Can you create a responsive website for the iPhone and Android?

Comment: U can have a class library project where all your data model and business logic are located, then two other projects for MVC WebSite and MVC Web API.